# Writing AVRO data to Hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, avro

I've a java Kafka consumer that's consuming avro data from kafka [say topic x]. It's supposed to push this data to HDFS as it is without code generation. In avro [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html) they're using something like the following:

```
GenericRecord e1 = new GenericData.Record(schema);      
e1.put("key", "value");

DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);

DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(datumWriter);
dataFileWriter.create(schema, new File("<HDFS file path>"));

dataFileWriter.append(e1);
dataFileWriter.close();
```

Problem with this is, I already have the avro data. To use this sequence of steps I have to extract each key-value pair after deserializing the avro packet, and then push it to a GenericRecord object, which I don't think makes any sense. I didn't find any example of what I'm trying to achieve. Any hint or link to relevant documentation is very much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of implementing your own Kafka->HDFS ingestion tool, have you considered using Kafka's built-in Kafka Connect framework combined with an existing Kafka->HDFS connector such as [kafka-connect-hdfs](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs)? The linked HDFS sink connector supports Avro out of the box.

Comment: Because of some schema-registry issues we've moved away from confluent. So I can't use confluent frameworks.

Comment: Care elaborating the schema registry issues you have been running into?  Can also be done via https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues of course.

Comment: Well, let's say we've one schema for a json doc with 10 key-value pairs. We need to support updating any of those 10 fields, and clients can send us partial data, i.e. docs with < 10 key-value pairs. We can't use the existing schema in that case, as any partial doc is a different json altogether. Using default values don't help either. Also if we have multiple sub-schemas [e.g. header and body], we can't refer to those in the super-schema [for the lack of a better word] using schema registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly, I suggest you trying com.twitter.bijection.Injection and  com.twitter.bijection.avro.GenericAvroCodecs packages, for example.

Take a look here http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/03/04/kafka-spark-avro-producing-and-consuming-avro-messages.html. 
There, in Kafka producer the GenericRecord is converted to bytes[], which are put in Kafka topic, and then in consumer this bytes are inverted into a GenericRecord according to your schema. And you don't need to put the values to all fields in record. After that you can write this record to file.

And, also you probably need to access file in HDFS some other way, since you cannot create a File instance for it.